# How to enable aero with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics, aero, dwm

I just reinstalled windows 7 on my computer, and aero is not working anymore. I did not change any hardware or drivers, and aero worked before reinstalling windows.

I am using a nVidia GeForce GTX 560 for the primary display and Intel HD 2000 for the secondary display, and I have a Experience Index of 7.5.

I already tried `net stop uxsms - net start uxsms` as suggested in many of the links google provides, but it still does not work.

What else could I do to enable aero again?

Edit:

I just found this in the event viewer:

```
The Desktop Window Manager did not start because an analysis of the hardware and configuration indicated that it would perform poorly.
```

Also, starting without graphics card works. But I still want to use the card, so this is not a solution for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to re-enable aero effects in Windows 7 after it has crashed?](http://superuser.com/questions/28685/how-to-re-enable-aero-effects-in-windows-7-after-it-has-crashed), perhaps also check out [Windows 7 Aero theme's “greyed out” - no found fix](http://superuser.com/questions/396580/windows-7-aero-themes-greyed-out-no-found-fix?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007: a reboot doesn't fix it for me, so I guess it is a different problem (it didn't work since reinstalling windows). I already tried the solutions in your second link (fix-it, msconfig, experience index) but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rerun the Windows performance index test, maybe it thinks the graphics card is too weak.  Also, does it actually show the GTX560 in Device Manager (or maybe just a plain VGA card, due to lack of or broken drivers)

Comment: the device manager shows `Intel(R) HD Graphics` and `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560`. after rerunning the performance index, it still shows 7.5, and aero still does not work.