# Why are window frames defaulting to large un-themed black and gray lines for enterprise users in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gui, themes, border

I am using Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit with an admin account and all my windows have buggy looking dark and light gray lines around them like this:

[image]

By changing advanced performance settings in the control panel, I can fix it, but am unable to revert back to this look.

My question is not how to fix it. It is why am I seeing this in the first place? This is a "clean install" inasmuch as what image was given to me by the superadmin at my office.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/396580/windows-7-aero-themes-greyed-out-no-found-fix

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? - `By changing advanced performance settings in the control panel, I can fix it`